# Dynamic EF/Linq query comparing Guid/UniqueIdentifier values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to generate a where clause against a Guid/UniqueIdentifier column using a greater than statement.  My problem is I have to dynamically generate the query.  Here's an example of what I want:

```
myTable.Where(x => Guid.Empty.CompareTo(x.ADifferentGuidColumn) > 0)
```

Which generates this SQL (I'm using LINQPad to get the SQL here):

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 UniqueIdentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT <columns...>
FROM [myTable] AS [t0]
WHERE (@p0 > [t0].[ADifferentGuidColumn])
```

This is what I have.  This is in a much larger generic method where the `T` parameter is the table/domain model object.  It compiles, but blows up when creating `startPointBody` saying `The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.Guid' and 'System.Guid'.`

```
Guid startPoint = Guid.NewGuid(); //actual value in real code...
IQueryable<T> set = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
//find primary key
IProperty primaryKey = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T).FullName).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.FirstOrDefault();
//expression for column we're filtering
var startPointMember = Expression.Property(parameter, primaryKey.Name);
ConstantExpression startPointConstant = Expression.Constant(startPoint, startPoint.GetType());
var startPointBody = Expression.GreaterThan(startPointMember, startPointConstant);
var startPointWhereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(startPointBody, parameter);
query = query.Where(startPointWhereExpression);
```

You can see in the example of what I want that I'm actually using `Guid.CompareTo()`, but I have no idea how to write that in this dynamic fashion.  I was hoping I could cheat since the generated SQL is just doing a simple `>` comparison, but EF caught me.

Comment: I'm struggling with what you're trying to do here. Are you saying that you don't know in advance which table you will be `SELECT`ing against? And that's the reason why a dynamic query is needed?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the table is, hence the dynamic stuff.  It's been running for a few weeks now.  I needed to add this where clause today and ran into this wall since `>` doesn't exist/isn't implemented for Guid types.

Comment: I'm walking out of my apartment to get some food and chew on this, but would it be possible to just implement GreaterThan for Guid types?

Comment: See [C# Expression to use Guid bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355917/c-sharp-expression-to-use-guid-bookmark/55357174#55357174) and [Entity Framework Core: Guid Greater Than for Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920200/entity-framework-core-guid-greater-than-for-paging/54929035#54929035)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution with example data.  I put this together in linqpad connected to a local sql server instance in docker.

Here's the table and data (some guids are hard coded in the demo code):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [col1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into test (col1,col2) values ('d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448', '09e0073a-be0e-405a-9564-d34056c8e42a')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448', 'a7a5aee0-87f4-42bb-90ac-dac7b52bffbf')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448', '104ab3c0-8521-453f-bf48-552358618a90')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448', '6128657b-5c84-4c95-afbf-4bfe06c2c7ea')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448', '96bc5a4f-0baf-44fb-a85c-fbddcca82ff9')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('ac15b74b-593f-4d28-9f80-46cc84a89e79', 'db4621e0-b6fe-40ad-a4c5-601f875c5bbf')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('a5071253-3a12-45c8-a495-d96bb56f49c9', 'a4536fa3-922a-43b0-a568-abfcf2daba9f')
insert into test (col1,col2) values ('a3cf9625-787a-4d91-a692-e2db8eb246a2', 'b7b7d1f9-b9cc-4201-bf75-40b0c4c2d301')
```

And here's the full program you can run in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    Test<Test>();
}

static void Test<T>() where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty("col1");

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    //create where clause expression
    var orgIdMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "col1");
    ConstantExpression orgIdConstant = Expression.Constant(new Guid("d3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448"), typeof(Guid));
    var orgIdBody = Expression.Equal(orgIdMember, orgIdConstant);
    var orgIdWhereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(orgIdBody, parameter); 

    TypedDataContext d = new TypedDataContext();

    var query = d.Tests.AsQueryable().Where(orgIdWhereExpression);

    //create start point expression 
    Guid startPoint = new Guid("09e0073a-be0e-405a-9564-d34056c8e42a");

    var startPointMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "col2");
    ConstantExpression startPointConstant = Expression.Constant(startPoint, startPoint.GetType());
    var left = Expression.Call(startPointMember, typeof(Guid).GetMethod("CompareTo", new Type[] { typeof(Guid) }), startPointConstant);
    var right = Expression.Constant(1);
    var startPointBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    var startPointWhereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(startPointBody, parameter);
    query = query.Where(startPointWhereExpression);

    MemberExpression keyMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "col1");
    var keyExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, Guid>>(keyMember, parameter);
    query = query.OrderBy(keyExpression);

    query.ToList().Dump();
}
```

There's a LOT of extra crap in here, but the actual answer to my question is where I define the `left` variable and the 4 lines after.  I did all of this in LINQPad because of it's SQL feature, which shows this SQL as the output:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 UniqueIdentifier = '09e0073a-be0e-405a-9564-d34056c8e42a'
DECLARE @p1 UniqueIdentifier = 'd3aaaf86-d4e5-4d77-897e-1b36c1100448'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[col1] AS [Col1], [t0].[col2] AS [Col2]
FROM [test] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[col2] > @p0) AND ([t0].[col1] = @p1)
ORDER BY [t0].[col1]
```

EDIT: it appears theres a bug/deficiency in EF Core's query generator when creating an expression like what I'm trying to do with `starPointWhereExpression`.  In my testing, it seems that when it gets to that expression, it gives up and tries to execute what it has against the server and saves any further expressions for local processing.  I say this because after where this code is running, I add `Skip()` and `Take()` expressions.  When the where expression comparing Guids is in the pipeline, the skip and take statements are NOT in the generated SQL.  If I don't add it to the pipeline, those statements do make it into the generated SQL.

EDIT 2: I filed [a bug on github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17633) about this.  This will be addressed in EF Core 3.  As of this writing (tested against EF Core 3 preview 9), the generated SQL is definitely odd and could use some work.